# Closing because of duplicates

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inefficient placement of the “Vote to Close” button for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93170/inefficient-placement-of-the-vote-to-close-button-for-duplicates)

Could we have an extra Close button at the top, so when i paste the URL in i don't have to wait for the question to load, scroll down and the press the moved close button?

I want to be able to just paste the url and click, without having the button jump down when the question is loaded.

Comment: I addressed everything in there — the AJAX loading and the moving button is really annoying. Actually, I just placed a bounty.. let's see.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks, voted to close mine, +1 yours.

Comment: So - should we close this as duplicate? *wink*

Comment: @Sklivvz If you can still find the button after it's scrolled down :P