# Improve usability for closing questions as duplicates

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inefficient placement of the “Vote to Close” button for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93170/inefficient-placement-of-the-vote-to-close-button-for-duplicates)

At the moment, closing a question as a duplicate always offers this small pang of annoyance.

You choose the duplicate and start moving your mouse pointer to the button but oh crap, when you arrive the preview of the duplicate has loaded and the button has gone down (quite a lot, if the question is long). Now you need to scroll so you can click the close button.

See this for what I mean: http://screencast.com/t/ftYpcSNGo1

Change-request: Make button indipendent of content length!

Comment: You can usually just press Enter to submit it.

Comment: My hands are not on my keyboard.

Comment: Fairly sure this is a duplicate :)

Comment: Well, if you find the original, try to close this one and you'll see what I mean :). I did look for duplicats though, before I posted this.

Comment: I know what you mean, which is why I think it is a duplicate. However, I can't find it right now.

Comment: I can't be bothered to close this as a duplicate because it's so damn annoying with the current UI.

Comment: :] well, I took it onto myself for the cost of yet another pang.