# "vote to close" button jumps around

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inefficient placement of the “Vote to Close” button for duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93170/inefficient-placement-of-the-vote-to-close-button-for-duplicates)

When voting to close a question the position of the button its self will jump around on the page depending on where you are in the menu.

[image]

When it shows up (left) the button is at one spot.

Lets say I click into "exact duplicate". The thing you don't see in the screen shot is the ajxy-magic that first doesn't contain the descriptive content for the default when you pick it. So for an instant my eyes find the button, only to have the button thrown to the bottom of the page beyond the window boundary.

I just want the action button to have one fixed position so regardless of what happens it doesn't fly around the form like it does now. Maybe we can move the vote box to the top?

Comment: @Lix Good, good. Everything is moving according to plan. Mauahahahahaha.

Comment: I guess they want you read the full page, before you click the button. `:)`