# White-space in close dialogue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, meta, design

A lot of white space has suddenly appeared in the close dialogue on Meta Stack Overflow, probably because of the lack of NARQ?

It looks like there is more than there was previously on beta sites and Android, though not to anywhere near the same degree as on MSO.

[image: Whitespace example]

Comment: It's added for the new "Close as duplicate" layout which take up the whole space. +1 for the cool unicorn though!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I thought it would be, but meta is a special case for the size of the box due to having fewer close options.

Comment: Might be true, but expanding the dialog will irritate even more people and make them weep harder. ;)

Comment: +1 for the free-hand circle, +one BILLION dollars for the free-hand unicorn. If it's free-hand. If not, you must burn.

Comment: Also - what happened to NARQ? I can't seem to find a meta-discussion about it. I fail at using SE's search engine.

Comment: Alternately, vertically center the list between theheader and bottom button and it would look much less silly

Comment: Looks like some recent changes to the VTC code broke things: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/close-question-reasons-overflow-the-box

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93170/the-vote-to-close-button-for-duplicates-is-inefficiently-placed-and-shouldnt

Comment: Guys... this is **intended** and a bugfix of [*The “Vote to Close” button for duplicates is inefficiently placed and shouldn't move away*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93170/the-vote-to-close-button-for-duplicates-is-inefficiently-placed-and-shouldnt) as [@Shog9 just commented](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166152/white-space-in-close-dialogue#comment486142_166152) with just a link.

Comment: Now somebody needs to resubmit the "add more migration targets" request so it can be closed because "there isn't enough space in the dialog"

Answer (score 4):

Don't think this is a bug. The new design for the "close as duplicate" is taking this whole space:

> [image]

So it's either having that extra space initially or having to expand the dialog vertically which I think will be even more annoying.

Comment: As it's got scroll bars *anyway*, why not just make the duplicate box shown above smaller on meta?

Comment: @Rory good point. But only 3 visible questions then scroll the rest still feels less comfortable..

Comment: Don't forget, the same layout is also used for the Q&A preview after you select a question - shrinking that up more would kinda hurt.

Comment: @Shog9 fair point, it just looks so icky though :L

Comment: Yeah... Guess we'll have to add a new close reason. **Closed as Makes Unicorns Weep by Rory**

Comment: @Shog that's about the best suggestion I've heard for looong time!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a *bug*, but it still looks wrong.  I liked [Ben Brocka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166936/ben-brocka)'s idea of vertically centering the list to avoid any complex changes or exceptions for sites with different numbers of close vote options, however it didn't look that much better when I mocked it up:

[image: View when centred]

Even if this isn't a bug in the strictest sense of the word I still think it's worthy of being fixed by either:

1. Making the close box smaller on meta and showing fewer duplicates before scrolling down
2. Making the close box smaller on meta for the first window, having it grow on the next step of the workflow then re-implementing this [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93170/the-vote-to-close-button-for-duplicates-is-inefficiently-placed-and-shouldnt) so we don't all go crazy (although looking at Shog's latest edit on it I guess this isn't too likely).

Comment: Jeremy was concerned that moving the button up would confuse it with search... I can kinda see that.